# SQLite.net do an insert with Foreign key

Tags: sqlite, insert, foreign-keys, mvvmcross

What is the best solution to save correctly my database :
I want to save this datas in my sqlite databse and export it in CSV, i made a little method, but with this process i can't get the PhotoEnt in my EmailEntity.

PhotoEntity :

```
 public class PhotoEntity : EntityBase
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public override int Id { get; set; }

    public string IdGuid { get; set; }

    public string PhotoDate { get; set; }

    public string Image { get; set; }

    [OneToMany]
    public List<EmailEntity> Emails { get; set; }
}
```

EmailEntity :

```
public class EmailEntity : EntityBase
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public override int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(typeof (PhotoEntity))]
    public string IdGuid { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    [ManyToOne]
    public PhotoEntity PhotoEnt { get; set; }
}
```

And, when i saved, i do this :

```
private void DoInsertBddCommand()
    {
        var guidForId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        var dateTime = DateTime.Now.ToString();

        var photoEntity = new PhotoEntity
        {
            IdGuid = guidForId,
            Image = _imageName,
            PhotoDate = dateTime
        };
        new PhotoBusiness().Save(photoEntity);

        foreach (var item in Emails)
        {
            var emailEntity = new EmailEntity
            {
                IdGuid = guidForId,
                Email = item,
                PhotoEnt = photoEntity
            };

            new EmailBusiness().Save(emailEntity);
        }
    }
```

It's my first time with SQLite.net, any suggestion ?

Thank you

Comment: are you using Sqlite.Net-Extensions?

Comment: Yes ! My nugget : http://i.imgur.com/ACgKVnH.png

Comment: Cool. Also why are you using two Id parameters (IdGuid and Id)? Couldn't the foreign key to PhotoEntity just point to the int Id property on the PhotoEntity object? I just want to make sure I understand your scenario before I post an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so here is how I would setup your models:

```
 public class PhotoEntity : EntityBase
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public override int Id { get; set; }

    public string PhotoDate { get; set; }

    public string Image { get; set; }

    [OneToMany(CascadeOperations = CascadeOperation.All)]
    public List<EmailEntity> Emails { get; set; }
}

public class EmailEntity : EntityBase
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public override int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(typeof (PhotoEntity))]
    public int PhotoEntityId { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    [ManyToOne(CascadeOperations = CascadeOperation.All)]
    public PhotoEntity PhotoEnt { get; set; }
}
```

Notice that I define the cascade operations in the relationship attribtues. This is directly from the SQLite-Extensions docs: https://bitbucket.org/twincoders/sqlite-net-extensions#markdown-header-cascade-operations

Now when you save/retrieve objects you need to use the recursive methods:

```
GetWithChildren
InsertWithChildren
```

https://bitbucket.org/twincoders/sqlite-net-extensions#markdown-header-cascade-read